# Suppose $Y \subset X$, both are continua of dimension one. If $\check{H}^1(X;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, is $\check{H}^1(Y;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuum-theory

Suppose $X$ is a continuum (a compact connected Hausdorff space, not necessarily metrizable) of dimension one and $Y$ is a subcontinuum of $X$ (i.e. a subspace of $X$ which is a continuum). If the first Cech cohomology group $\check{H}^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial, must it also be the case that $\check{H}^1(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ be trivial?

I don't believe this is true, but I can't seem to find a counterexample. The only dimension one continua with trivial first Cech cohomology group which I can think of at the moment are the pseudoarc and the arc, but both are hereditarily equivalent, so they won't work. I definitely could be completely wrong in my belief as I am very inexperienced in algebraic topology, so if there is a simple reason as to why this is true, then it would be great to know why.

Comment: "Dimension one" in what sense?

Comment: @freakish Lebesgue covering dimension

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti why? I only know Urysohn's theorem that states that they are equal for normal and second countable spaces.

Comment: I always assume continua to be metrizable, I didn't notice that those of the asker aren't necessarily so. For compact Hausdorff spaces we only have the inequalities $\dim X\leq\mathrm{ind}(X)\leq\mathrm{Ind}(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer I assume that by dimension you mean Lebesgue covering dimension (or the cohomological dimension).

There are no such continua. The reason is that for a finite-dimensional compact Hausdorff space, cohomological dimension equals covering dimension. On the other hand, integer cohomological dimension of a space $X$ is the least $n$ such that there exists a closed subset $A$ such that the pull-back map
$$
p: \check{H}^n(X)\to \check{H}^n(A)
$$
is surjective: see the discussion and references [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Homological_dimension_of_a_space)).

A textbook proof of the equality of covering and cohomological dimensions (assuming that the space has finite covering dimension) can be found for instance in
Theorem VIII.2 in

*Nagata, J.*, Modern dimension theory. Rev. and ext. ed, Sigma Series in Pure Mathematics, Vol. 2. Berlin: Heldermann Verlag. IX, 284 p. (1983). [ZBL0518.54002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0518.54002).

In your situation, if $\check{H}^1(X)=0$, then surjectivity of $p$ implies that for each closed subset $Y\subset X$ (regardless of its connectivity), $\check{H}^1(Y)=0$.

Comment: "cohomological dimension equals covering dimension" doesn't this statement depend on the cohomology theory?

Comment: @freakish: In this context, it is always understood as Chech with integer coefficients.